# ChemistryData — where is specific gravity?

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

I cannot seem to find the basic chemical property specific gravity with `ChemicalData` or other comparable functions.

Comment: Do chemists (and scientists in general) ever actually use specific gravity rather than density?

Answer (score 15):

Specific gravity is not on the property list of curated chemical properties, so you can't get it directly. However, here is a function that will compute it.

```
With[{h2oDens = ChemicalData["Water", "Density"]}, 
  specificGravity[name_String] := ChemicalData[name, "Density"]/h2oDens]

specificGravity["Ethanol"]
```

> `0.789`

```
specificGravity["Gold"]
```

> `19.3`

Answer (score 8):

Another version, not that fast, but still for the record:

```
specificGravity[name_String]:=
    WolframAlpha["specific gravity "<>name,
    {{"SpecificGravityPod1:ChemicalData",1},"ComputableData"}]

specificGravity["gold"]
```

`Out[]=19.3`